# What are the factors that can affect the frequency of light?

Tags: visible-light, magnetic-fields, frequency

As far as I was informed, I have found out that for a magnetic field to affect the frequency of light, it has to be so strong that it can compete against the mass-gravities of planets. So, since it seems a bit too hard to be done in the earth itself, I am looking for alternative solutions to affect the frequency of light. 
I do thank you all for your help and attention.

Comment: Could you give some references for your information?

Comment: Do I understand correctly, you have a beam of light, and you want to change its frequency? You don't just want to get a source with a different emission frequency? Do you already know about [acousto-optic modulators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acousto-optic_modulator) and [optical parametric amplifiers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_parametric_amplifier)?

Comment: [Compton scattering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compton_scattering)?

Comment: @ThePhoton - I think that the OP looks for effects that change the frequency of propagating light in free space. He mentioned  the question with respect to a magnetic field which you can find here https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/385994/is-it-possible-to-change-the-frequency-of-the-light-by-magnetic-fields .

Answer (score 1):

You can use gravitation itself! The most accurate [optical atomic clocks](http://You%20can%20use%20gravitation%20itself.%20The%20most%20accurate%20clocks%20using%20light%20can%20detect%20a%20change%20in%20gravitational%20potential%20on%20the%20earth's%20surface%20by%20just%20lifting%20the%20clock%20by%202cm!) using light can detect a change in light frequency due to gravitational time dilation caused by the gravitational potential on the earth's surface by lifting the clock just by 2cm!

If you are looking for other factors accomplishing a frequency change in free space, you have to consider that gravitation is related by Einstein's field equations to the energy-momentum tensor which comprises not only matter, but also radiation and all not gravity related force fields.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a way to change the frequency of light in a laboratory experiment, it's easy:  send the light through an acouso-optic modulator.  If the AO modulator is driven at a frequency of f and light entering the AO modulator has a frequency of F, then light exiting the AO modulator has a frequency of F+f or F-f, depending on whether you use the -1 or +1 diffraction order.